# Splitting on JSON Payload with Regex to get Value

Tags: java, regex, split

I am attempting to get a value out of a partial JSON payload just using the "split" method. I can only use this method since this API is very limited. I can get my value using Pattern and match APIs..

```
package com.company;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        String myString = "{\n" +
                "  \"8\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"TEST\": \"LN17ELJ\",\n" +
                "      \"ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE\": \"2172752\",\n" +
                "      \"ORDER_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE\": \"109197634\",\n" +
                "      \"STATUS\": \"HORLEY\",\n" +
                "      \"SECONDARY_NAV_CITY\": \"HORLEY\",\n" +
                "      \"ROUTE\": \"THE STREET 12\",\n";


        String myRegexPattern = "\"([ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE\"]+)\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]+)\",?";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myRegexPattern);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);


        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Didn't work!");
        }
    }
}
```

However; When I try and using String.split it doesn't work and my value is not in any of the array indexes..

```
package com.company;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        String myString = "{\n" +
                "  \"8\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"TEST\": \"LN17ELJ\",\n" +
                "      \"ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE\": \"2172752\",\n" +
                "      \"ORDER_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE\": \"109197634\",\n" +
                "      \"STATUS\": \"HORLEY\",\n" +
                "      \"SECONDARY_NAV_CITY\": \"HORLEY\",\n" +
                "      \"ROUTE\": \"THE STREET 12\",\n";


        String myRegexPattern = "\"([ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE\"]+)\"\\s*:\\s*\"([^\"]+)\",?";

        String[] newValue = myString.split(myRegexPattern);

        for(int i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
            if(newValue[i].equals("2172752")) {
                System.out.println("IT'S HERE!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What would be the best way to do this? Is there a better way to get ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE with just using split??

Comment: Do you realize that `[...]` is a character class, i.e. that `[ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE"]+` is equivalent to `[_CDEFINOQRTU"]+`?

Comment: If you're developing an API, wouldn't it be potentially better to follow something along the lines of [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-validation-example/)? I appreciate that you initially said that it's very limited, but just how limited are we talking?

Comment: Why would you want to use `String.split()`? You should be able to split at the position right before and after ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE as well as before and after the following value but the expression would become quite complex and hard to handle. Thus I'd say you should stick to `Pattern` and `Matcher` if you _have_ to use regex. However, since your data seems to be json I'd suggest using a proper parser instead anyway.

Comment: @Thomas I'm glad we're on the same wavelength(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your regular expression isn't doing what you are expecting. It is not matching `"ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE":"...",` but matching any key that starts with any of the letters in ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE. You could replace it with something like `\"ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE[\"\\s:]+([^\",]+)` which will match what you are after in matcher group 1.
2. The split function doesn't work as you expect. The regular expression you are using in the split is viewed as the delimiter. Thus it is removing the data you are hoping to extract.

Assuming you are looking to get all of the values for ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE, in the case there is more than one `ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE` in your real data, your first example is closer to what you are after.

1. You need to fix your regular expression and matching group
2. Use a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement to find all the instances

```
    String myRegexPattern = "\"ROUTE_UNIQUE_ID_REFERENCE[\"\\s:]+([^\",]+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myRegexPattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```